# Show and hide loading status in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, hide, loading, show, mask

I've found some documentation for pinning a loading mask to any ExtJS element, but I need it to behavior other way. I want to explicitly write a show instruction somewhere and a hide one elsewhere. Didn't find anything like that by now...

Thanks in advance for any idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this :

```
function loadMask(el,flag,msg){
    var Mask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.get(el), {msg:msg});
    if(flag)
        Mask.show();
    else
        Mask.hide();
}
```

refer this : [Load Mask](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/source/LoadMask.html#cls-Ext.LoadMask)

Comment: @Giku It refers to the dom element. The content will be injected into that

Comment: @Giku el : for element id. e.g 'grid'/'form'

Comment: I'm asking because it seems the mask still needs to be rendered to an element, the case I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Giku  on which component you are trying to loadMask

Comment: @MMT, a gridpanel; but I couldn't stick the mask to it because of an error displaying my grid has no method getUpdater(). Same when I tested the grid's store. However, I got it solved by using `Ext.getBody()` instead of `Ext.get(el)`.

Thank you for the function. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the post, now I know I need to call show() for the mask to work. Was causing some head-scratching.